# trying to understand gcp cloud costs and determine free or low cost relational database hosting?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I was originally planning to use Azure SQL for a client's database but Azure said that the estimated cost was going to be something around $250/month for the most basic configuration.  I remember when using Azure for my own experimentation in the past, that Azure costs were higher than expected so I decided to look at GCP as an alternative.

GCP offered me a free trial credit of $300 so I accepted that by default.  I created a new SQL Server instance via my GCP account, created the most basic database configuration, then connected via SSMS and created a single database table with a single Id column.  That's it.  Now, 2 days later with no additional usage of this database table, my GCP free trial credit has been burned down by $15.  Based on this trend, a SS instance on GCP seems to cost about as much as an Azure SQL instance.  Am I inferring this correctly?

Can you recommend a good quality option which provides free relational database hosting for low volume, low transaction databases?  SQL Server would be great but MySQL should work too.  I'm assuming that MySQL is fairly equivalent for simple databases?

Comment: The pricing for SQL Server, for the most part, is determined by Microsoft SQL Server license fees.  Each cloud vendor has similar prices. If you need the features of SQL Server, then use SQL Server. The Developer version can be used for development and learning only (not public websites) and is very low cost. Otherwise look at MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL which are low cost open source alternatives. Note that these databases are similar to but not replacements for Microsoft SQL Server. Tip: before launching a service, using the vendor's pricing calculator to determine costs.

Comment: See also [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/) for free quotas/products.  The only database product that is free is Firestore for 1GB.  You could also use an F1-micro instance of a Compute Engine (1 free per month) and host your own open source database (MySQL?).

Comment: before comparing cost, compare features. As @Kolban said, you can host a tiny MySQL database for free on microvm. No backup, no update, nothing, but it's free and slow. With $100 per month you have 1 dedicated vCPU for MySQL/PostgreSQL engine, with nightly backup and regional High Availability with Cloud SQL and with automatic server update and patching. What's your requirements? Then we could talk about cost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about costs related to other cloud providers, but gcp's are usually really competitive on the market. With cloud SQL you pay per instance/h and you pay more/less based on different factors. Use the google cloud price calculator to have a general idea of the costs, and adjust cloud sql accordingly: [https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

Additionally, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) you may find all the information regarding Pricing details of Cloud SQL.